# Lower and Upper Bound for Ricci Curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, curvature

As mentioned in first chapter of *John M. Lee: Riemannian Geometry*, one of our goal in differential geometry is connecting geometry and topology. For this reason it is natural to compare curvature quantities with its correspondence in model spaces; e.g. $Ric \geq k g, Ric\geq0$. But I never seen any result about $Ric\leq kg$ or $Ric \geq -k g$ for some positive constance $k$.

> Does this conditions deduced from earlier one? or topology of this manifolds are so complicated to handle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There can be no topological consequences of estimates of the form $Ric \le k g$ or $Ric \ge -k g$ (at least in dimensions greater that $2$), because [this paper by Joachim Lohkamp](https://mathscinet-ams-org.offcampus.lib.washington.edu/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1307899) shows that every smooth manifold  of dimension at least $3$ admits a complete metric whose Ricci curvature is bounded between two negative constants.

**Addition:**

Your comments suggest that you may have some misunderstanding about what these inequalities mean. Here are some remarks that might help to clarify what's going on.

- First, an equality like $Ric\le k$ or $Ric \ge k$ is really shorthand for $Ric\le kg$ or $Ric \ge kg$.  Equivalent statements are that  $Ric(v,v)\le k$ (resp. $\ge k$) for every unit vector $v$; or $Ric(v,v) \le k|v|^2$ (resp. $\ge k|v|^2$) for every tangent vector $v$.    For example, if an $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold has sectional curvatures bounded above by a constant $c$, then its Ricci curvature is bounded above by $(n-1)c$.
- Second, note that the metrics whose existence is guaranteed by Lohkamp satisfy $Ric \le -k_2g$ for some positive constant $k_2$. By transitivity, such a metric therefore also satisfies $Ric \le k g$ for every positive constant $k$, so there is no topological consequence that can be deduced from any upper bound on Ricci curvature.
- Next, it certainly does not follow from Lohkamp's theorem (and it's not true) that no manifold admits a metric whose Ricci curvature is positive somewhere and negative somewhere else, as you seemed to suggest in a comment. In fact, every manifold admits such a metric -- you can just use a bump function to "paste in" a positively curved metric in one open set, and paste in a negatively curved metric in a different open set.
- Finally you asked what topological consequences can be deduced from estimates of the form $K\le k$ or $K\ge -k$ (where $K$ represents sectional curvature). The answer is none -- [this paper by R. E. Greene](https://mathscinet-ams-org.offcampus.lib.washington.edu/mathscinet-getitem?mr=510080) showed that every manifold admits a complete metric satisfying both of these inequalities.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you mean that all manifolds admit a metric with $Ric\leq k$ or $Ric \geq -k$?  what we can say about topological properties of manifolds with $K\leq k$ or $K\geq -k$?

Comment: @C.F.G: Lohkamp's theorem says that every manifold admits a metric with $-k_1g\le Ric \le -k_2g < 0$ for positive constants $k_1,k_2$.  Any such metric satisfies both of the hypotheses you asked about: $Ric \le -k_2g$ and $Ric \ge -k_1g$.

Comment: @C.F.G.: What do you mean by $K$?

Comment: Dear Prof. Jack Lee, note that one of my hypotheses is $Ric \le k_2g$ and not $Ric \le -k_2g$. $K$ denotes sectional curvature.

Comment: Is the hypotheses $Ric \geq -k_2$ equivalent to negative Ricci curvature as you mentioned above? i.e. No manifolds admit some positive somewhere and negative Ricci curvature somewhere.

Comment: .. and I don't understand that how you apply Lohkamp's theorem for $Ric\leq k$?

Comment: @C.F.G: See my addition above.

Comment: Awesome answer. Exactly as I wanted. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Hi Jack, it seems the link to the paper requires login to UW. Do you have the link to e.g. arxiv?

Comment: @ArcticChar The paper has the title "Metrics of negative Ricci curvature". I didn't find a version on the arxiv, but maybe you can access it through your institution.

Comment: @MaoWao Thanks. That's good enough.