# Bishop-Gromov-like inequality for upper bounded Ricci curvature?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, volume, curvature

Given a lower bound on the Ricci curvature of a complete Riemannian manifold $M$, the [Bishop-Gromov inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bishop%E2%80%93Gromov_inequality) allows us to deduce an upper bound on the volume of (geodesic) balls in $M$.

Is there a similar statement if we assume an upper bound on the Ricci curvature of $M$?  I.e., does such an upper bound allow us to deduce a lower bound on the volume of balls in $M$?

If it is easier, feel free to restrict your attention to just Hadamard manifolds.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2902375/lower-and-upper-bound-for-ricci-curvature) answer your question?

Comment: @Didier The linked answer only concerns topological consequences of upper Ricci curvature bounds, but this question here is about a geometric consequence.

Comment: Bishop-Gromov is proved using a differential inequality that holds only with a lower bound on Ricci. The proof involves the AMGM inequality which cannot be reversed without additional assumptions. With only an upper bound, the inequality does not imply anything about the volume.

Comment: And @Didier’s answer is in fact relevant. It is strong evidence that there is no geometric consequence because it usually does imply topological facts.